# Call to web service webmethod throws HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a piece of code in which there are 2 sequential calls to a good old ASMX web service.

```
service.Url = "http://.....";
service.A(1, 2, 3);
service.B(4, 5, 6);
```

Call to `A` is fine. But call to `B` throws `404... not found...` In discovery, both methods are visible and seem fine - I see both in IE, metadata looks good. I placed break point in `B` and it is definitely not hitting. I did rebuild, `Update Web Service` reference in consuming project and rebuilt it.

The status is `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError`.

Signature of failing web Method

```vb
<WebMethod(Description:="Store a fragment of object on server.")> _
Public Function B(
    ByVal p1 As String, 
    ByVal p2 As String,
    ByVal p3() As Byte, 
    ByVal p4 As Integer,
    ByVal p5() As Byte) As Boolean
```

The call is (verified)

```
bool result = service.B(string, string, byteArray1, int, byteArray2);
```

Again, WebMethod B is not reached. Web reference proxy and all - look good.
What can it be?

Comment: You probably have wrong url for your service try setting url of service to correct url lik service.Url = "http://<hostName>/directory/service1.asmx";

Comment: @Adil This is what exactly done. Ulr is set before calls to `A` and `B`

Comment: Copy that url and browse, if it is fine then rebuild your service, update reference and rebuild the consuming application

Comment: @Turbulence What exactly do you need? - Clearly, same url, same code base, 2 methods, one doesn't respond (not found) programmatically but is there when you place this URL into IE address bar and looks good there

Comment: @Adil done all that. This is why I ask the question. Could be environmental. Or, may be someone knows something, like, how to identify this issue smartly

Comment: Can you show both method definition just signature?

Comment: I am afraid there is a mis-match between the type you give in method call and type you have in signature. Try to resolve this. As you did not show the exact call I can't be sure.

Comment: It looks like issue with the parameters and arguments passed

Comment: @Turbulence, again, I have not changed the signature of the webmethod, nor calling client. But I will double-check.

Comment: @Adil I just did it again (rebuild, update reference, etc) and updated question with signatures. Was my mistake - I don't have any `by ref` in this call. All parameters have correct data type on break point. There is correct proxy, etc., but the service call is not reached. It is not found! Status is `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError`

Comment: Add the method call with data not with types. I think problem is with byte array. Remove these two parameter from both definition and call and see if it is reached.

Comment: @Adil, this doesn't make sense. This method has been there for years and was working with byte arrays. I have not changed the signature of this method. All code in question has been there. But after some work was done on another method, now, this call is failing. I will have to come back to it tomorrow.

Comment: This is definitely not an environment issue. As you say that the URL is same and no proxy issue can exist either. It's not an issue with GET/POST/PUT types as you will not have 404. Something to do with type of parameters mostly. Check if the webservice has been changed. You are a client isn't it?

Comment: @Adil I resolved it - see the answer. It was confusing error message for the most part

Comment: The error message "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" was not giving any clue or real problem but, second error message "Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value" is clear to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved it. It was confusing since I was getting `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` and `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError`.

Once I hooked-up *Fiddler2*, I was digging in it and found *WebView*, in which it clearly says:

> •Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the content length exceeds the configured value.

To resolve the issue I've changed configuration in IIS to allow 50MB requests.

[image: Edit request propertues]

And you also want to have following setting in web.config

```xml
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1000000" executionTimeout="3000"/>
```

Max setting is `2097151 KB`

`404` was confusing. It sounded like issue with web service while in reality it was the size of request. And when I said it worked before, it is simply because before I wouldn't save such large objects as I have to this time.

Comment: Extremely horrible to know that size of the request was causing HTTP 404 error. Simply a nightmare experience. I was also uploading a file as byte array in the web method argument which was exceeding the configured size in IIS. Thanks for helping us out.

Comment: @RBT Could be just Microsoft's way to obscure things a little. If you a real client, you may know that you can only upload file up to specific size. But if you are some hacker and just probing things, you get 404 and "ah, can't do this". Who knows?